# Need help Querying Report-as-a-service (RAAS) API with T-SQL

Tags: sql, rest, t-sql, postman

The problem is I am able to successfully connect to API with T-SQL, but when I alter the SQL to connect to a RAAS API I get 400 (Bad Request) status. I know the RAAS settings are correct because I can connect using Postman but when I try to use the same values in SQL I get nothing. I have to use RAAS API because the table I am connecting to is not available through the regular API so the company helped me set up a custom report that the RAAS connects to and contains the data I need.

This is the postman settings that do work:
[POSTMAN1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME0Wg.png)

This is the SQL that does NOT work. It does not fail, it just gives me a Status: 400 (Bad Request) and no data:

```
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max));

DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @XMLText AS VARCHAR(max);

DECLARE @Body AS VARCHAR(8000) = 
'{
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://HOSTURL/dataservices/bidata/2/IBIDataService/LogOn</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://HOSTNAME/services/BIDataService</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <LogOn xmlns="http://HOSTURL/dataservices/bidata/2">
            <logOnRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <UserName>ServiceUserName</UserName>
                <Password>ServicePassword</Password>
                <ClientAccessKey>USCustomerAPIKey</ClientAccessKey>
                <UserAccessKey>ServiceUserAPIKey</UserAccessKey>
            </logOnRequest>
        </LogOn>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
}';

-- Open the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST','https://HOSTNAME/services/BIDataService', 'false'
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body
-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUT;
-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @ResponseText;
/*need to insert into a table because it helps get around the 4000 character limit which causes nulls*/
INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
SELECT @XMLText = Json_Table from @json;

SELECT @ResponseText AS ResponseText, @Object as Object, @XMLText as XMLText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @Object
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

/*Clean up*/
DELETE FROM @json;
```

The above SQL comes from this block of code that I have used frequently and DOES work. The difference though is this API uses GET while the RAAS API uses POST and the RAAS API parameters are in the body and not passed through the header.

Working code from previous API's:

```
/*We need this to prevent a json error (error 13609)*/
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max));
 
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @XMLText AS VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @hr varchar(255); 
-- Open the connection.
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
-- Send the request.
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get','https://HOSTNAME/personnel/v1/person-details?Page=1&per_page=3000', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'US-Customer-Api-Key', 'USCustomerAPIKey'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Authorization', 'Basic base64-encrypted-ServicePassword'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null
-- Handle the response.
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
/*need to insert into a table because it helps get around the 4000 character limit which causes nulls*/
INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
SELECT @XMLText = Json_Table from @json;

-- Show the response.
SELECT @ResponseText AS ResponseText, @hr AS hr, @Object as Object, @XMLText as XMLText;

/*Clean up*/
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
DELETE FROM @json;
```

And here's the postman settings for the SQL that does work for comparison:
[POSTMAN2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFNlr.png)